# LibGDX: How to optimize asset handling in an Android game?

Tags: java, android, optimization, libgdx, assets

```
Assets{
       static Assets instance;
       AssetGamePlay play;
       class AssetGamePlay{
           AtlasRegion block2;
           -----code-----
       }
}
```

This the simplified look of my class.

I'm calling the variable block2 by `Assets.instance.play.block2`

I'm calling many variables like this around 40-60 times in a second (render function).

So my question is (Android games):

1. Is this a very costly way to do this ? If yes then how can I improve?
2. My class flow is actually saving a bit RAM so I implemented.

Comment: May I ask what problem you encounter exactly? I cannot imagine that this handling of assets may cause any kind of performance bottleneck. You should program however you want, and then run it. When it runs fine, leave it, when it doesn't then you do profiling and change only the parts that cause problems. You should not start with micro optimizations which you will never ever notice anyhow.

Comment: @noone I knw sir this is a micro optimization. but making games  for LDPI i have to take  such optimizations into account.Well anyway i found my method very efficient .thanx to you guys ...

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it like this, but use an [`AssetManager`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) instead, which already offers access in this way, but even more features as well.

I usually do it like this:

```
public class YourGame {

    public static AssetManager assets = new AssetManager();

    // load all necessary assets via the manager in advance

    // use the manager like this anywhere in your code:
    YourGame.assets.get("block2", Texture.class);

}
```

Comment: I'm making AssetManager .Sry that i dint mentioned here (thought its quite obvious ). Thankx for your help ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in making an inner class inside Assets. Why don't you make it directly, so this:

```
Assets.instance.play.block2;
```

Becomes this:

```
Assets.instance.block2;
```

If you have the assets divided by logical use (play, menu, etc) then use methods to load/unload them (using [Assetmanager](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html) like [noone suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045343/1895303)).

Also, if you are using a singleton, you may want to have a method that gets the instance and if it doesnt exists, creates it.

```
public static Assets getInstance(){
    if(instance==null) instance = new Assets();
    return instance;
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
Assets.getInstance().block2;
```

without having to worry about the static instance being lost for whatever reason.

And finally:

> Is this a very costly way to do this?

**Nop**, it is not. I handle it like that all the time.

Comment: Sir I made the getinstance() but to post here i just did it minimum lines. That was my bad ,Sry for that.

Comment: i'm making inner class to make my Assest class more segregated .n m also doing DYNAMIC LOADING . so  will create the object of AssetGAMEPLAY when the user cliks on play btn and will release the object whn user goes back to main menu.

Comment: Then you're good. Don't worry about performance, this won't affect much @Vineet

Comment: Even if i make methods for loadGAMEPLAYASSETS() and  unloadGAMEPLAYASSETS().  I will be able to unload the assets only not the variables that were made to hold them.(ie. in my example AtlasRegion block2).This block2 will occupy my memory till i dont destroy this Assets class(if i declare it in Assets class).

Answer (score -2):

If this is Java, outers class(`Assets`) will only have access to static members of the inner (`AssetGamePlay`).
But if you have an instance and the attribute is public on the inner you can do a getter method like:

```
Assets{
    static Assets instance;
    AssetGamePlay play;
    class AssetGamePlay{
        AtlasRegion block2;
        //-----code-----

    public AtlasRegion getBlock2(){
        return Assets.instance.play.block2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is adding anything useful here. You basically just repeated what he already said in the question.

Comment: I corrected, there was a `}`. instead using `Assets.instance.play.block2` he will use `Assests.getBlock2()`

Comment: He said "This the simplified look of my class.". His question is not how to access his fields, but about asset handling on android via libgdx. Your answer does not help him.

Comment: @lauksas Sir you are doing the same thing as i did and your way is costly than mine .

Comment: I was hoping the JVM compile this method to native code due to high usage. I guess Adroid JVM does not work like the Oracle one. Never mind...